Ceph encountered problems after running "ceph dashboard iscsi-gateway-add -i 1.conf images"
I have correctly configured 3 storage nodes and 1 c
ontrol node (the control node has storage node services), as well as correctly configured iSCI storage. However, I have noticed that in order to view iSCI monitoring on the dashboard, relevant content must be configured
ceph dashboard iscsi-gateway-add  -i 1.conf images


conf contains the following content
http://admin:admin@192.168.100.10:5588
http://admin:admin@192.168.100.20:5588
http://admin:admin@192.168.100.30:5588


After running successfully, it displays' Success'
However, there were issues later on, such as the dashboard homepage not functioning properly and the monitoring ISCSI gateway in the dashboard not being available.
And there were also related errors on the command line.
root@node1:~#  ceph dashboard iscsi-gateway-list
Error EINVAL: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/mgr_module.py", line 1759, in _handle_command
    return CLICommand.COMMANDS[cmd['prefix']].call(self, cmd, inbuf)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/mgr_module.py", line 462, in call
    return self.func(mgr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/services/iscsi_cli.py", line 21, in list_iscsi_gateways
    return 0, json.dumps(IscsiGatewaysConfig.get_gateways_config()), ''
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/services/iscsi_config.py", line 104, in get_gateways_config
    return cls._load_config_from_store()
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/services/iscsi_config.py", line 47, in _load_config_from_store
    cls.update_iscsi_config(config)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/services/iscsi_config.py", line 64, in update_iscsi_config
    service_url=service_url).get_hostname()['data']
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/services/iscsi_client.py", line 42, in instance
    port = url.port
  File "/lib64/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 181, in port
    port = int(port, 10)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5588http:'

My requirement is to restore to a normal state and successfully configure monitoring
thank you

The iscsi-gateway support is deprecated. Although you might get it to work, there's no guarantee that you'll get help from the community when something breaks.
If you can, use RBDs directly instead of a gateway in between, or wait until NVMe-oF becomes production ready.

hi 【eblock】.Okay, but I need to revert back to normal now. What should I do now.thanks

You probably just need to remove the gateways from the dashboard gateway list, at least I assume that. Look at ceph dashboard iscsi-gateway-list and then try to remove them with ceph dashboard iscsi-gateway-rm <name>.

Sorry, even after running this command, the error output mentioned above still appears. I suspect that the configuration above may have contaminated the Ceph database

Can you paste the output of ceph config-key get mgr/dashboard/_iscsi_config?

OK
root@node1:~# ceph config-key get mgr/dashboard/_iscsi_config
{"gateways": {"images": {"service_url": "http://admin:admin@192.168.100.10:5588\nhttp://admin:admin@192.168.100.20:5588\nhttp://admin:admin@192.168.100.30:5588"}}}root@node1:~#

Can you just remove the key with ceph config-key rm mgr/dashboard/_iscsi_config and then try reloading the dashboard. If it fails, do a mgr failover (ceph mgr fail).
